# Applying jQuery Resizable on a dynamically generated html data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I need your help.

I can't seem to get the jQuery Resizable API to work on my dynamically generated Datatable once it has been generated. It seems the function calls it after it has completed but I get an error "object expected"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<!-- LOAD JQUERY LIBRARY: -->  
    <link   href="/jq/images/jquery-ui.css"         type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/jq/jquery.min.js"         type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="/jq/jquery-ui.min.js"      type="text/javascript"> </script>

<style type="text/css">
#mstrWrapper {
        position: relative;
        height: 200px;
        width: 800px;
        border: 1px solid #808080;

        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        scrollbar-base-color: #DFDFDF;
        scrollbar-arrow-color: #235A81;

}

#mstrTable {
        width: 800px;
        color: #235A81;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 9pt;
        border: 0px;
}

#mstrTable th, #mstrTable td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
        border-right: 1px solid #808080;
        padding: 3px;
}

#mstrTable th {
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#cdcdcd");
        width: 110px;
        height: 18px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
        border-top: 0px;
}


#mstrTable tbody tr:first-child td {
        padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
#mstrTable tr.normal td {
    color: #235A81;
    background-color: white;
}
#mstrTable tr.highlighted td {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #235A81;
}

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
var table
var tbody
var ishigh

function writeit() {

var html = '<table id="mstrTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ui-widget-content">\n'
    html +='<thead>\n'
    html +='<tr> \n'
    html +='<th>File Number<\/th>\n'
    html +='<th>Date1<\/th>\n'
    html +='<th>Date2<\/th>\n'
    html +='<th>Status<\/th>\n'
    html +='<th>Num.<\/th>\n'
    html +='<\/tr>\n'
    html +='<\/thead>\n'
    html +='<tbody>\n'
    html +='<tr> \n'
    html +='<td>KABC<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>09\/12\/2002<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>09\/12\/2002<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>Submitted<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>0<\/td>\n'
    html +='<\/tr>\n'
    html +='<tr> \n'
    html +='<td>KCBS<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>09\/11\/2002<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>09\/11\/2002<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>Lockdown<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>2<\/td>\n'
    html +='<\/tr>\n'
    html +='<tr>\n'
    html +='<td>WFLA<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>09\/11\/2002<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>09\/11\/2002<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>Submitted<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>1<\/td>\n'
    html +='<\/tr>\n'
    html +='<tr> \n'
    html +='<td>WPPP<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>03\/19\/2003<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>03\/19\/2003<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>In-Progress<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>0<\/td>\n'
    html +='<\/tr>\n'
    html +='<tr> \n'
    html +='<td>WRRR<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>02\/19\/2002<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>02\/19\/2002<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>Submitted<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>5<\/td>\n'
    html +='<\/tr>\n'
    html +='<tr>\n'
    html +='<td>WTTT<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>02\/19\/2002<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>02\/19\/2002<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>In-Progress<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>0<\/td>\n'
    html +='<\/tr>\n'
    html +='<tr> \n'
    html +='<td>WYYD<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>02\/11\/2002<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>02\/11\/2002<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>Submitted<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>7<\/td>\n'
    html +='<\/tr>\n'
    html +='<tr> \n'
    html +='<td>WRRR<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>02\/19\/2002<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>02\/19\/2002<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>Submitted<\/td>\n'
    html +='<td>5<\/td>\n'
    html +='<\/tr>\n'
    html +='<\/tbody>\n'
    html +='<\/table>'

document.getElementById('mstrWrapper').innerHTML = html


$( "#mstrTable tr th" ).resizable({  handles: 'e' });  

}
</script>


</head>

<body>
<div id="mstrWrapper"></div>

<input type="button" value="LOAD" onclick="writeit()">

</body>

</html>
```

It seems the code fails on this line, I don't see anything wrong, and it should work:

```
$( "#mstrTable tr th" ).resizable({  handles: 'e' });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really not sure where the problem is, but here is a solution : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/CGNq5/)

The only thing i advice you  not to do is this :

```
<input type="button" value="LOAD" onclick="writeit()">
```

but write it like this:

```
$("#load").on("click",writeit);
```